# My iPad won't turn on

Tags: ipad

I turned my iPad off fully (with the whole "slide to shut off" thing) and then turned it back on. After a few minutes the lock screen came up, showing 86% battery, but the finger controls weren't working. now i can't even get it to turn on. What do I do?

Comment: Do you have a computer you‘ve connected the iPad Tobin the past?

Answer (score -1):

Hold the **Home** and **Power** buttons at the same time.  Keep holding until the Apple logo appears.  Release the buttons and it should reboot.  That might fix yor problem.